# .config vs. .env files in node.js w/ heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, configuration-files

I'm in the process of doing my first deployment of a node.js app on Heroku.  While running the app locally I stored API keys and other configuration variables in .config files excluded from version control.

Heroku seems to have built-in support for a ".env" configuration file in the project root and I've refactored my server code to support this.  My question is where is the best place to store configuration variables that need to be accessible in the client?  I'm running angularjs on the front-end and need to be able to access various API keys.

Is there some way I can reference the same .env file or should I be approaching this differently?